# Network Connection between Win 10 and Win NT

Tags: network-shares

i work in a work group with main machine (server) as work group, it work fine until a new laptop with win 10 is connected to our work group, this lap top can see all other machines can use transfer files between, only he can not access Server (with win NT) always refused the connecting for any share folder or running a program between, all other machine use win 7 with no problems, it think it is a problem between win NT an win 10, if any one have a solution

Answer (score 0):

Windows NT probably uses the SMBv1 protocol, which Windows 10 considers to be
outdated and insecure, so it is disabled by default.

Enabling the SMBv1 protocol in Windows 10 is done by running `optionalfeatures.exe`,
placing a check-mark next to "SMB 1.0/CIFS File Sharing Support" and click OK.
Restart is required.